# Alternative to GoSub in VB.net

Tags: vba, vb.net, vb6-migration

I'm assigned a project to replace all the `GoSubs` in an application based off of `VBA` because this application is switching to `VB.net` and `GoSubs` are not supported there. Here's a simplified version of the original code:

```vb
Sub Main ()
  Dim A As String
  ...
  If ConditionX Then A = "Black"
  Else A = "White"
  End If
  ...
  GoSub Execute
  ...
  Execute:
    Call BuiltInSub1 (A)
    Call BuiltInSub2 (A)
    'where BuiltInSubs are some predefined procedures within the application
    ...
  Return

End Sub
```

I'm thinking about using a `Call` to replace `GoSub` as follows:

```vb
Sub Main ()
  Dim A As String

  If ConditionX Then A = "Black"
  Else A = "White"
  End If
  ...
  Call Execute
  ...

End Sub

Sub Execute ()
   ...
   Call BuiltInSub1 (A)
   Call BuiltInSub2 (A)
   ...
End Sub
```

The obvious error of my modified version above is that variable `A` is not declared in `Sub Execute`. One option I can think of is redefining `A` in `Sub Execute`, but to do that, I will need to re-declare all variables used to define `A` in Main, where there are quite a few.

What would be the best/most efficient way to replace `GoSub` in my case?

Comment: You don't use the `Call` keyword in VB.NET.  You can, but it does nothing useful.

Comment: You should do exactly as you have done there and move the subroutine code into a method and then simply add a parameter to that method for each variable that is shown to be undeclared. If the variable is set anywhere in the method, you would need to declare the parameter `ByRef`.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my comments above, your code should look like this:

```
Sub Main ()
  Dim A As String

  If ConditionX Then A = "Black"
  Else A = "White"
  End If
  ...
  Execute(A)
  ...

End Sub

Sub Execute(A As SomeType)
   ...
   BuiltInSub1(A)
   BuiltInSub2(A)
   ...
End Sub
```

If you do find that you need declare parameters `ByRef`, you might want to look at refactoring as a more long-term solution.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that lamda functions may have nested variable scope) in VB.net

```
Dim A
Dim B
Dim xecute = function()
    BuiltInSub1(A)
    BuiltInSub2(A)
End Sub
A = 1
B=xecute()
A=2
B=xecute()
```

Comment: It would be better to create a method with a parameter if the subroutine is used more than once tho?

Comment: Is it better to create objects with no private data? Passing all data between methods using public data and parameterized methods? Sometimes, but not always.